# Add a class to an element depending on column value; Using WebMatrix sql database, Cshtml(Razor) and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I created a static HTML quiz app (containing 200 questions) using JavaScript. Now to make it dynamic i am using WebMatrix 3. The database table consists 6 columns namely: questions, choiceA, choiceB, choiceC, choiceD and correctchoice. This is the partial code of my 'cshtml' file...

```
@foreach(var row in data){
<ol type="1" class='questions'>
<div class="qnum" >
    <li><span id="qstn">@row.question:</span></li>        
    <ol id="q1" >
        <li id="A"><span>@row.choiceA</span></li>
        <li id="B"><span>@row.choiceB</span></li>
        <li id="C"><span>@row.choiceC</span></li>
        <li id="D"><span>@row.choiceD</span></li>
    </ol></div>
</ol>
if(@row.correctchoice == A){ 
<script>        
    $("li#A").addClass("true");
</script>
}
if(@row.correctchoice == B){ 
<script>        
    $("li#B").addClass("true");
</script>
}
if(@row.correctchoice == C){ 
<script>        
    $("li#C").addClass("true");
</script>
}
if(@row.correctchoice == D){ 
<script>        
    $("li#D").addClass("true");
</script>
}
}
```

Now for testing i have only 4 questions in database with correct choices A,B,C,D respectively. But the above code does this for me: For first Question the 'true' class is added to all list items. For second, its added to 2nd,3rd and 4th items. For third, its added to 3rd and 4th list items. And for fourth to 4th item only...
So unfortunately, the above code is working for 4th question only.....

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. I updated the code as..

```
@{
    if(@row.correctchoice == A){
<li class="true"><span>@row.choiceA</span></li>
    } else{ <li><span>@row.choiceA</span></li> }

    if(@row.correctchoice == B){
<li class="true"><span>@row.choiceB</span></li>
    } else{ <li><span>@row.choiceB</span></li> }

    if(@row.correctchoice == C){
<li class="true"><span>@row.choiceC</span></li>
    } else{ <li><span>@row.choiceC</span></li> }

    if(@row.correctchoice == D){
<li class="true"><span>@row.choiceD</span></li>
    } else{ <li><span>@row.choiceD</span></li> }
}
```

So better we don't directly relate JavaScript to dynamic content of database.